# UITextView内のカーソル位置に文字を追加

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

#### 環境

swift3
Xcode9.0.1

#### 実現したいこと

UIButtonを押すと、UITextView内のカーソル位置に文字を挿入するためにはどのようにしたら良いでしょうか。

#### 例

UITextViewの内容が

> あいうえおさしすせそ

とあり、'お' と 'さ' の間にカーソルがある時
ボタンを押すと

> あいうえおかきくけこさしすせそ

となるようにしたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記のように`insertText(_:)`メソッドを使います。

```
textView.insertText("かきくけこ")
```